# php шаблонизатор

Tags: php, шаблонизаторы

Как это правильно сделать? Подскажите пожалуйста.
Есть результат запроса:

```
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

кусок из шаблона:

```
$new = '';
<?php foreach($messages as $message): ?>
if($new != $message->title): // проверяем новый ли это блок
    <div><?php echo $message->title; ?></div>
    <ul> // если это новый блок то создаем для него ul
<?php endif; ?>
<li>$message->text</li> // здесь контент для ul
------------------------> Тут якобы нужно закрыть <ul> Как и где его закрыть? =) Что бы было правильно!
<?php endforaech; ?>
```

Получится должно так:

```
<div>title</div>
<ul>
    <li>text</li>
    ...
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После foreach и перед if добавьте ещё один

```
if($new != '')
(вывод) </ul>
```

Comment: После foreach и if...